# Get the values from JSON string using NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

How can i get values from the following `JSON`.

JSON

```
{
    "X": [
        {
            "one": 1,
            "two": "Bill"
        },
        {
            "one": 2,
            "two": "Hutch"
        }
    ]
}
```

CODE

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;


 dc =[dictionary objectForKey:@"X"];
```

Now how can i print the value of "one" and "two"

NB : `dc` is a `NSMutableDictionary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here is your JSON

> {
>       "X": [
>           {
>               "one": 1,
>               "two": "Bill"
>           },
>           {
>               ***"one": 2***,
>               "two": "Hutch"
>           }
>       ] }

To get the second object from X array and in that value of "one" :

```
NSString *value = [[[dictionary objectForKey:@"X"] objectAtIndex: 1] objectForKey: @"one"];
```

Here is explanation into multiple line for the same code used above in single line:

```
  NSArray *arr = [dictionary objectForKey:<Root Key String>]; // save data to array from dictionary
  NSDictionary *dict = [arr objectAtIndex: <Index of object>]; // get the actual object from array based on index
  NSString *resultString = [dict objectForKey: <Key String>]; // get value of your required key
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code..

```
    NSString *str = @"{\"X\":[{\"one\": 1, \"two\": \"Bill\" }, { \"one\": 2, \"two\": \"Hutch\" } ] }";
   str = @"{\"X\":[{\"one\": 1,},{\"one\": 2,\"two\": \"Hutch\"}]}";
    NSError *jsonError;
    NSData *objectData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                           error:&jsonError];
    NSLog(@"%@",[json objectForKey:@"X"]);

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [json objectForKey:@"X"];
    for (NSDictionary *tempDict in dict) {
        NSLog(@"%@",tempDict);
        if ([tempDict objectForKey:@"one"]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",[tempDict objectForKey:@"one"]);
        }
        if ([tempDict objectForKey:@"two"]){
            NSLog(@"%@",[tempDict objectForKey:@"two"]);
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you :)